# Limit Problem using L'Hospital's Rule Transformation

Tags: limits, derivatives

Find $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left[x /\left(e^{x}-1\right)\right]^{1 / x}$

It seems obvious that the initial step should be taken using an exponential function, where the new form yields $\frac{\ln(\frac{x}{e^x-1})}{x}$. However, L'Hospital's rule does not work in this case. Are there any possible alternatives to transform the given expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, $\dfrac{x}{e^{x}-1}\rightarrow 1$ by L'Hopital.

So $\log\dfrac{x}{e^{x}-1}\rightarrow\log 1=0$, so the limit in question is in L'Hopital form.

It becomes
\begin{align*}
&\lim\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{x}{e^{x}-1}}\dfrac{(e^{x}-1)-xe^{x}}{(e^{x}-1)^{2}}\\
&=\lim\dfrac{e^{x}-1-xe^{x}}{x(e^{x}-1)}\\
&=\lim\dfrac{e^{x}-e^{x}-xe^{x}}{e^{x}-1+xe^{x}}\\
&=\lim\dfrac{-xe^{x}}{e^{x}-1+xe^{x}}\\
&=\lim\dfrac{-e^{x}-xe^{x}}{e^{x}+e^{x}+xe^{x}}\\
&=\lim\dfrac{-1-x}{2+x}\\
&=-\dfrac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Apply the rule $$L = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(\frac{x}{e^x-1})}{x} = \lim_{x\to0}\left( \frac{e^x-1}{x}\cdot\frac{e^x-1 -xe^x}{(e^x-1)^2}\right)$$
But note that
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$$
and
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1 -xe^x}{(e^x-1)^2} = -\frac12 \tag{why?}$$
Hence $L = -1/2$.

Comment: Wonderful, appreciate it!